# Помогите в public function в PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, база-данных, функции

Здравствуйте, пишу функции для сохранения и обновления данных с массива в БД через форму. Есть 2 документа:

**ProductAdmin.php**

```
$razmers = array();

if($this->request->post('razmers'))
    foreach($this->request->post('razmers') as $n=>$ra)
    {
        foreach($ra as $i=>$r)
        {
            if(empty($razmers[$i]))
                $razmers[$i] = new stdClass;
            $razmers[$i]->$n = $r;
        }
    }

if(is_array($razmers))
{
    $razmers_ids = array();
    foreach($razmers as $index=>&$razmer)
    {
        if($razmer->stock == '-' || $razmer->stock == '')
            $razmer->stock = null;

        if(!empty($razmer->id))
            $this->razmers->update_razmer($razmer->id, $razmer);
        else
        {
            $razmer->product_id = $product->id;
            $razmer->id = $this->razmers->add_razmer($razmer);
        }
        $razmer = $this->razmers->get_razmer($razmer->id);
        if(!empty($razmer->id))
            $razmers_ids[] = $razmer->id;
    }
    $current_razmers = $this->razmers->get_razmers(array('product_id'=>$product->id));
    foreach($current_razmers as $current_razmer)
        if(!in_array($current_razmer->id, $razmers_ids))
            $this->razmers->delete_razmer($current_razmer->id);

    asort($razmers_ids);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($razmers_ids as $razmer_id)
    {
        $this->razmers->update_razmer($razmers_ids[$i],array('position'=>$razmer_id));
        $i++;
    }
}
```

**Razmers.php**

```
public function update_razmer($id, $razmer)
{
    $query = $this->db->placehold("UPDATE __razmers SET ?% WHERE id=? LIMIT 1", $razmer, intral($id));
    $this->db->query($query);
    return $id;
}

public function add_razmer($razmer)
{
    $query = $this->db->placehold("INSERT INTO __razmers SET ?%", $razmer);
    $this->db->query($query);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда сохраняешь данные через форму, данные не записываются и не обновляются, а браузер выводит ERROR 500. Надеюсь на вашу помощь, т.к. сам сижу над этим 4 день. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Лог ошибок с сервера добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @Visman, как это сделать?

Comment: На сервере открываете файл error.log (из папки logs сервера apache) и смотрите, что за ошибки в самом конце файла. Добавляете их в свой вопрос через правку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/746640/edit

Comment: @SlamStreetwear, то есть... я всё правильно понял? Вы берете так, foreach в последнем цикле, и прямо в цикле при этом **вручную** перебираете индекс? Прекратите так делать немедленно. И больше никогда не делайте. Что Вы вообще хотели сказать теми строчками кода? от `$i = 0;` и до конца цикла.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский , в БД есть колонка position и я могу заполняя таблицу переставлять значения, например не 1,2,3, а 1,3,2 или 2,3,1 и т.д.. Эта функция и отвечает за эту сортировку

Comment: Хорошо, а ошибку из лога покажете всё-таки?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский, та я бы с радостью, но не могу открыть файл. Пишет "/var/log/apache2/domains/мой сайт.ua.error.log: open for read: permission denied.
Ошибка: Передача файла потерпела неудачу"